# Cannot redirect ip traffic with iptables to new ip on linux centOS

Tags: iptables

today I able to migrate some of the game servers to another server and needed some help to redirect the traffic from old ip to the new one.

SERVER1 1.1.1.1 ----- (internet ) -----> SERVER 2.2.2.2

I asume to use iptables to perform this, for that used this rule on my centOS box in the server1.

> /etc/sysctl.conf: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dest 1.1.1.1 --dport 27015 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:27015
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 2.2.2.2 -p udp --dport 27015 -j SNAT --to 1.1.1.1
```

But the client cannot connect to the server from the old ip, the redirection don't started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something along these lines:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p all -d 1.1.1.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p all -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't have any NAT configured previously on this server, you may not have the kernel set to pass IPv4 traffic.

Make sure you have this in your `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Comment: ip forwarding is enabled, but I have the same problem.